# 'Invalid value for 'x_range' Bokeh Gmap error

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, plot, bokeh

The code below is giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid value for 'x_range', MapPlot ranges may only be Range1d, not data ranges
```

I'm almost certain there's nothing wrong with the code considering I had it working with no errors up until today.

I don't think this is relevant, but it stopped working after I ran the following in my command terminal:

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:5000 -s tcp:listen | sudo xargs kill
```

I restarted my computer several times (in hopes of reseting the ports) but that hasn't worked either.

My code is below:

```
from bokeh.models import (
   GMapPlot, GMapOptions, ColumnDataSource, Circle, DataRange1d, PanTool, 
   WheelZoomTool, BoxSelectTool
)
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, output_notebook

output_notebook()


map_options = GMapOptions(lat=30.29, lng=-97.73, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)

plot = GMapPlot(
x_range=DataRange1d(), y_range=DataRange1d(), map_options=map_options
)

plot.title.text = "Austin"


plot.api_key = "INSERT PERSONAL GOOGLE API KEY"


completed_lats = [30.265872,30.2900002]

completed_longs = [-97.749270,-97.733322]

completed_source = ColumnDataSource( data=dict(
    lat=completed_lats,
    lon=completed_longs,))

completed_dots = Circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=50, fill_color="blue",
                        fill_alpha=0.1, line_color=None)
plot.add_glyph(completed_source, completed_dots)


plot.add_tools(PanTool(), WheelZoomTool(), BoxSelectTool())

show(plot)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is in fact a problem with the code, it is this:

```
plot = GMapPlot(

    x_range=DataRange1d(), y_range=DataRange1d(), # BAD

    map_options=map_options
)
```

Exactly as the message states, only `Range1d` can be used with `GMapPlot`. This is because unlike regular Bokeh plots, Google Maps maintains complete control of the plot's axes dimensions. This is inconsistent with using a `DataRange1d`, because those *also* try to control the axes dimensions, which can lead to unpredictable and undesirable results.

There was a time before Bokeh checked for this, and would allow `DataRange1d` to be passed. Once it was discovered that combination was causing problems, a check was added to explicitly disallow it. You just need to use a `Range1d` instead (you don't need to set `start` or `end`):

```
plot = GMapPlot(

    x_range=Range1d(), y_range=Range1d(), # GOOD

    map_options=map_options
)
```

However, I should also point you to the [`gmap`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/gmap.py) function, which makes creating Google Maps plots *much simpler*. With that it is much like `figure` in that a reasonable default plot is created automatically, no need to create and add ranges at all. It was announced in [version 0.12.5](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/4/5/release-0-12-5/).

Comment: This worked! You saved me hours of mindlessly staring at my screen. I was perplexed because it was working yesterday morning and stopped working in the afternoon.

Comment: I'm glad it's working, my best guess it you are somehow using a different (newer) version of Bokeh now.